# Flash suddenly doesn't work well with a long video

Tags: google-chrome, flash, microsoft-edge

I am doing a long Udemy course (online training) which seems to use Flash.

So far everything worked fine (using Chrome browser).

Since of today, I have a lot of problems

- Regularly (read: every 5 minutes or less) the video stops, restarts, pauses.
- I could regulate the playback speed, but sometimes a new 'flash player' in a flash player seems to be shown, without playback speed

The problem happens in both Edge and Chrome (same problems).

What I tried:

- Removed flash player browser data within the Flasy Player's control panel settings
- Allowing Flash in Chrome (was already), and removed cache

I'm using a very recent Chrome/Edge version, and Windows 10.

**EDIT**

I noticed I have the problem only with a very long Flash video: 2.5 hours.
All others are max. 70-80 minutes, and mostly less and seem to play well.

My PC is not young, but it's not slow in general (i7, 16 GB, SSD).

Comment: Perhaps it's not a problem with you, but with Udemy.

Comment: @user96931  I checked again, and I notice all other Udemy video's play well, but the difference is that this one is 2.5 hours... I will add it in my question. Thanks for the valuable remark.

Comment: Hmmm, it could be your RAM usage. If you're on Windows, open up Task Manager before you go to the page with the video. Watch if it spikes when the page loads. It should go up a little, but you know RAM is the problem if your RAM usage approaches your total capacity.

Comment: No spikes, I am using 40-50% (it varies slightly), and using thus about 7-8 GB. My Google Chromes use 20% (I have many open, but closing others doesn't help regarding the restarts of the Flash).

Comment: If it's possible, try scaling down video quality.

Comment: @user96931 Sorry for my late answer, I had to do some checks, but it seems to work now (at least for several minutes), the video quality is not very good anymore (360p) but better than crashes. If you put it as answer, I can upvote/accept if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible, try scaling down video quality.

Comment: Thanks! (btw, I also tried lowered the playback speed, also works). So it's a matter of internet speed probably (although I have reasonably fast internet). Anyway, your solution works (too).